# How to add parent campaign members to child with different status?

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

We are using campaigns as course and lesson attendance.
The parent campaign is the course name, and each weekly lesson is a child campaign.

```
-- Math K3
---- Math K3 20181204
---- Math K3 20181211
etc...
```

All kids are added as campaign members (CM) to the parent campaign with 'Registered' status, and for each week, we want to add only those who attended, with 'Attended' status.

I can't use a report, since I can't select which to add.

I want to be able to look on all the 'Parent' CM's, and select which to add to the weekly meetup.

Any ideas how I can?

If possible, using declarative methods only.

Answer (score 1):

Following OOTB approach might help you but it has some manual work to do.

The Campaign Members should have a status of `Registered` and `Attended`. During addition to the Parent Campaign  you can mark campaign members as `Registered`. You can also update status though Process Builder if needed.

2nd part the manual process involved and user may or may not like it, but approach is OOTB. Let's say, if you are adding Contacts as Campaign Member, then create a List View Based on that Parent Campaign, like this:

[image: List View]

And, then, when you choose the child campaign, you could filter based on this list view as follows:

[image: Adding Members]

That way, at-least filtered list of members will be displayed.

Cons part is, you need to change this List view frequently for other Campaigns, or you need to create this kind of Campaign based list views for other Parent Campaigns.

Comment: Thank you OOTB is tedious and manual. I am looking for something that will be more adaptive to the user, and easy to manage.

Comment: Let's wait for other members to respond this